# How do I keep the following makefiles from recompiling all source code when one or more source files are changed?

Tags: c++, makefile

How do I keep the Makefiles that are at https://github.com/Zero3K/hpsx64 from recompiling all source code when only one or more of the source code files have changed so that way people can be able to make changes to it without having to wait for it to compile the changes? Here's one of them:

```
DIR_COMMON = ./common
DIR_PLATFORM = $(DIR_COMMON)/WindowsAPI
DIR_HPS1X64 = ./hps1x64/src

INC_COMMON = -I$(DIR_COMMON) -I$(DIR_COMMON)/StringUtilities -I$(DIR_COMMON)/breakpoint/src -I$(DIR_COMMON)/debug/src -I$(DIR_COMMON)/DiskImage/cd/src -I$(DIR_COMMON)/x64Encoder/src -I$(DIR_COMMON)/config/src
INC_PS1_PLATFORM = -I$(DIR_HPS1X64)/hps1x64/src/ -I$(DIR_PLATFORM)/GUIHandler/src/ -I$(DIR_PLATFORM)/WinFile/src/ -I$(DIR_PLATFORM)/DebugValueList/src/ -I$(DIR_PLATFORM)/DisassemblyViewer/src/ -I$(DIR_PLATFORM)/InputBox/src/ -I$(DIR_PLATFORM)/DebugMemoryViewer/src/ -I$(DIR_PLATFORM)/BreakpointWindow/src/ -I$(DIR_PLATFORM)/Joystick/src/

DIR_PS1 = $(DIR_HPS1X64)
DIR_PS1_R3000A = $(DIR_PS1)/r3000a/src
DIR_PS1_CD = $(DIR_PS1)/cd/src
DIR_PS1_GPU = $(DIR_PS1)/gpu/src
DIR_PS1_DMA = $(DIR_PS1)/dma/src
DIR_PS1_INTC = $(DIR_PS1)/intc/src
DIR_PS1_MDEC = $(DIR_PS1)/mdec/src
DIR_PS1_SPU = $(DIR_PS1)/spu/src
DIR_PS1_SIO = $(DIR_PS1)/sio/src
DIR_PS1_PIO = $(DIR_PS1)/pio/src
DIR_PS1_TIMER = $(DIR_PS1)/timer/src
DIR_PS1_BUS = $(DIR_PS1)/databus/src
DIR_PS1_SYSTEM = $(DIR_PS1)/system/src

INC_PS1_R3000A = -I$(DIR_PS1_R3000A) -I$(DIR_PS1_R3000A)/execute -I$(DIR_PS1_R3000A)/lookup -I$(DIR_PS1_R3000A)/print -I$(DIR_PS1_R3000A)/COP2 -I$(DIR_PS1_R3000A)/recompile -I$(DIR_PS1_R3000A)/cache
INC_PS1_CD = -I$(DIR_PS1_CD)
INC_PS1_GPU = -I$(DIR_PS1_GPU)
INC_PS1_DMA = -I$(DIR_PS1_DMA)
INC_PS1_INTC = -I$(DIR_PS1_INTC)
INC_PS1_MDEC = -I$(DIR_PS1_MDEC)
INC_PS1_SPU = -I$(DIR_PS1_SPU)
INC_PS1_SIO = -I$(DIR_PS1_SIO)
INC_PS1_PIO = -I$(DIR_PS1_PIO)
INC_PS1_TIMER = -I$(DIR_PS1_TIMER)
INC_PS1_BUS = -I$(DIR_PS1_BUS)
INC_PS1_SYSTEM = -I$(DIR_PS1_SYSTEM)
INC_PS1 = $(INC_PS1_R3000A) $(INC_PS1_CD) $(INC_PS1_GPU) $(INC_PS1_DMA) $(INC_PS1_INTC) $(INC_PS1_MDEC) $(INC_PS1_SPU) $(INC_PS1_SIO) $(INC_PS1_PIO) $(INC_PS1_TIMER) $(INC_PS1_BUS) $(INC_PS1_SYSTEM)



SRC_PS1_PLATFORM = $(wildcard $(DIR_HPS1X64)/hps1x64/src/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(DIR_PLATFORM)/GUIHandler/src/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(DIR_PLATFORM)/WinFile/src/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(DIR_PLATFORM)/DisassemblyViewer/src/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(DIR_PLATFORM)/InputBox/src/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(DIR_PLATFORM)/DebugMemoryViewer/src/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(DIR_PLATFORM)/BreakpointWindow/src/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(DIR_PLATFORM)/Joystick/src/*.cpp)
SRC_COMMON = $(wildcard $(DIR_COMMON)/StringUtilities/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(DIR_COMMON)/breakpoint/src/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(DIR_COMMON)/debug/src/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(DIR_COMMON)/DiskImage/cd/src/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(DIR_COMMON)/x64Encoder/src/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(DIR_COMMON)/config/src/*.cpp)

SRC_PS1_R3000A = $(wildcard $(DIR_PS1_R3000A)/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(DIR_PS1_R3000A)/execute/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(DIR_PS1_R3000A)/lookup/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(DIR_PS1_R3000A)/print/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(DIR_PS1_R3000A)/COP2/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(DIR_PS1_R3000A)/recompile/*.cpp)
SRC_PS1_CD = $(wildcard $(DIR_PS1_CD)/*.cpp)
SRC_PS1_GPU = $(wildcard $(DIR_PS1_GPU)/*.cpp)
SRC_PS1_DMA = $(wildcard $(DIR_PS1_DMA)/*.cpp)
SRC_PS1_INTC = $(wildcard $(DIR_PS1_INTC)/*.cpp)
SRC_PS1_MDEC = $(wildcard $(DIR_PS1_MDEC)/*.cpp)
SRC_PS1_SPU = $(wildcard $(DIR_PS1_SPU)/*.cpp)
SRC_PS1_SIO = $(wildcard $(DIR_PS1_SIO)/*.cpp)
SRC_PS1_PIO = $(wildcard $(DIR_PS1_PIO)/*.cpp)
SRC_PS1_TIMER = $(wildcard $(DIR_PS1_TIMER)/*.cpp)
SRC_PS1_BUS = $(wildcard $(DIR_PS1_BUS)/*.cpp)
SRC_PS1_SYSTEM = $(wildcard $(DIR_PS1_SYSTEM)/*.cpp)
SRC_PS1 = $(SRC_PS1_R3000A) $(SRC_PS1_CD) $(SRC_PS1_GPU) $(SRC_PS1_DMA) $(SRC_PS1_INTC) $(SRC_PS1_MDEC) $(SRC_PS1_SPU) $(SRC_PS1_SIO) $(SRC_PS1_PIO) $(SRC_PS1_TIMER) $(SRC_PS1_BUS) $(SRC_PS1_SYSTEM)



INC = $(INC_PS1) $(INC_COMMON) $(INC_PS1_PLATFORM)
SRC = $(SRC_PS1) $(SRC_COMMON) $(SRC_PS1_PLATFORM)
LIBS = -lglew32 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lgdi32 -lComctl32 -lkernel32 -lwinmm -ldinput8 -ldxguid
CFLAGS = -w -Wl,-subsystem,console -mwindows -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -DGLEW_STATIC -O3 -DUSE_PS1_GPU_TEMPLATES
#-Wl,--stack,134217728
#-Wl,--stack,16777216
OBJ = hps1x64


$(OBJ): $(SRC)
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```

Comment: You mean changes to the makefiles? How should the make tool know that a change to the make file does not affect the whole build?

Comment: You will need to completely rewrite it. That makefile is written to compile the whole program in one compiler invocation.

Comment: I mean the changes to the source code.

Comment: I see that there's a generic makefile at https://github.com/yqbear/adxm. How do I modify it to act like the one that is shown?

Comment: Your dependency rule is "all the object files depend on all the source files", so...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
$(OBJ): $(SRC)
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```

Frankly, that's a terrible rule.

Instead, you can do something like this:

```
${OBJDIR}/%.o : src/%.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```

Okay, adding this. This is an actual `Makefile` I just wrote:

```
SRC = foo.cpp bar.cpp

OBJS := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,${SRC})

echo: 
    echo ${OBJS}
    
%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -c --std=c++17 $^ -o $@
   
foo: ${OBJS}
    g++ ${OBJS} -o foo
```

So, if we apply this to your Makefile above, near the bottom:

```
OBJS := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,${SRC})

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ ${CFLAGS} ${INC} -c $^ -o $@

$(OBJ): $(OBJS)
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```

Note that the last pair of lines has a change. `$(OBJ): $(SRC)` becomes `$(OBJ): $(OBJS)`.

What this does:

```
OBJS := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,${SRC})
```

This creates a new variable named OBJS that takes the SRC variable and changes every xxx.cpp to xxx.o.

```
%.o: %.cpp
    g++ ${CFLAGS} ${INC} -c $^ -o $@
```

This is a generic rule for compiling xxx.cpp into xxx.o

```
$(OBJ): $(OBJS)
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```

This is the original rule, but instead of depending upon SRC, it depends on the individual .o files.

Comment: You still have to declare `$(OBJ)` as a target and have it depend on all the _object_ files and provide a recipe to link it all together, or it won't work.  Also, your recipe here must create the object directory, else the compile will fail.

Comment: That doesn't work. It tells me mingw32-make: *** No targets.  Stop. when I run the batch file that uses the .txt file that is the Makefile being used to build it.

Comment: @MadScientist Can you please provide the part to replace and what to replace it with?

Comment: Or can anyone else?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's a windows-only project, and I'm on Mac and Linux. I'll try to add a bit more help, but I can't test anything I do.

Comment: That still doesn't work

Comment: @JosephLarson it can be made to work on Mac/Linux.

Comment: I couldn't find directions for building on any environment on which I have a build environment. Perhaps you can find a windows dev who can do it. Otherwise you're going to have to learn Make.